# iOS animation: Drop down that keeps it position

Tags: animation, ios6, uikit

I´m trying to create a drop down menu that will display a set of controls. I got the animation working but the whole "button" moves with the animation.

My button is a UIView which is named settingsPanel, this is my code so far:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        self.settingsPanel.bounds = CGRectMake(self.settingsPanel.bounds.origin.x, self.settingsPanel.bounds.origin.y, self.settingsPanel.bounds.size.width, self.settingsPanel.bounds.size.height + 300);
}];
```

I just want the height of the panel to change, and it does, but the whole view moves up a bit as well.

How can I create a animation that justs increases the height downwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `frame`, not the `bounds`.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    self.settingsPanel.frame = 
        CGRectMake(self.settingsPanel.frame.origin.x, 
                   self.settingsPanel.frame.origin.y, 
                   self.settingsPanel.frame.size.width,  
                   self.settingsPanel.frame.size.height + 300);
}];
```

Frame is an *external* coordinate. When you change the frame, you change the actual position of the view within its superview, so you can keep the origin and width the same and just increase the height.

Bounds is an *internal* coordinate. When you change the bounds, the system has to decide what to do about the frame; its solution is that the change happens around a stationary center position. So the top moves upward as the height grows downward.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Do you happen to know if there is a way to make the views height changed from the bottom of the view? So the animation will look like it gets lower.

Comment: Just set the frame however you want. You might have to use some elementary arithmetic...!

Comment: By the way, if you do not understand frame and bounds, my book might help you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_frame

Comment: And you might enjoy my chapter on animation: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_view_animation